# Debugging Node.js in Eclipse - skip certain files

Tags: javascript, eclipse, node.js, debugging

When debugging Node.js with breakpoints in the debugger, is there a clever way to mark certain files as 'irrelevant', so that the debugger will step-over any and all code within these files, and only continue to break when code execution is out of this file again?

For example, when you have been awarded a library-size piece of code with a lot of promises and callbacks, seeing what's on the "other side" of e.g. a promise library, without prior knowledge, is one valuable use of this.

The way to do this now is to step over the code a hundred times until you are out of the file again and you can see where you've ended up. If the debugger could just do this automatically, I could be home an hour early every. :)

Answer (score 0):

No - if you are trying to debug specific code paths you are better off setting breakpoints on the "other side" where execution will resume after passing through code in these files. Then you can just tell the debugger to continue and wait for it to hit one of these points.

Comment: But when you have been awarded a library-size piece of code with a lot of promises and callbacks, seeing what's on the _other side_ without prior knowledge is exactly what I am trying to do.